# Imageview images responsiveness

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have 3 images in PNG format.They are in same resolution and i want them to be next to each other in a relative layout. I want it to be responsive for example the imageviews should resize them according to the space provided. I dont want to give a fixed height and width in dps like:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

And if i try to define width and height like:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And if i do, they are way too big.What should i do? Any recommendations ?

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/streetlong">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_hospital"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@drawable/hospital"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_pharmacy"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_hospital"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_hospital"
            android:background="@drawable/pharmacys" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_police"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_pharmacy"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_pharmacy"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/polices"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want the imageviews to adjust according to the screensize and i dont want to give them height and width

Comment: Use one horizontal linearlayout. put 3 image view in it. add weight to 1 in each imageview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using  property android:layout_weight

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```